# Grails Not Using Dev Database

Tags: database, grails, configuration

I have a grails project and my configuration points to a mysql database:

```
DataSource.groovy
    environments {
        development {
            dataSource {
                dbCreate = "update"
                url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb"
                driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                username = "root"
                password = "mypass"
                hibernate.dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"
            } 
        }...
```

When Grails runs, (using `grails dev run-app` or `grails run-app`) it is not connecting to this development environment at all, but instead is using a default development environment. I know this because none of the data in the mydb database can be seen, and new entries into the db are not persisted in mydb. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I get some error messages on startup that lead me to believe it is actually loading the right database:

```
2011-06-20 13:15:00,603 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Unsuccessful: alter table X add index FK9DBE53031937164 (a_id), add constraint FK9DBE53031937164 foreign key (a_id) references Y (id)
2011-06-20 13:15:00,607 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Can't create table 'mydb.#sql-2db_215' (errno: 150)
```

but see no indication that this would cause it to kick back to the default Grails environment or anything like that. Could this be related?

EDIT 2:

Config.groovy has the following:

```
environments {
    development
    {
        //Port
        grails.server.port.http = 9091

    }
```

but the application still runs on 8080.

Comment: Which file did you change the environment in?

Comment: @C. Ross - I updated the post. Does that answer your question? Thanks.

Comment: It's like it's not even picking up your config files, which is odd. Have you tried a `grails clean` to see if that changes anything?

Comment: @Rob Hruska - Yes, I have cleaned multiple times. Also, it looks like it is getting other parts of the configuration files loaded correctly, so I am not sure how to account for it. Also, the fact that the Hibernate error contains my database name seems like it is trying to use it, so I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @Rob Hruska - I just changed my password to an incorrect one and running the application correctly threw an exception, so it is using that section of the configuration.

Comment: @skaz - Definitely interesting. I don't have any more ideas, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually my problem (user error). It was pointing correctly to the correct database, but a series of problems caused the information to be written to a spot that made it look like it wasn't being written. My fault! Thanks for the help.